# vagrant up failing because of PPA: libapache2-mod-php5

Tags: vagrant, apache2, virtualbox

When I try to launch a new development environment running Ubunut in virtualbox I save my framework to a directory in Sites on my mac, then open terminal and cd to the directory with the Vagrantfile before running "vagrant up".  After an initial start I get several errors that end in the environment not starting.  The error is:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: apache2-api-20120211 but it is not                           installable. PreDepends: apache2 (>= 2.4)
```

When I try to upgrade the PPA, for example running the code:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
```

I get the error that add-apt and/or get-app command not found!  I do not know what to do.

[Vagrantfile and Provision script](https://github.com/jschnor/vagrant-config)

Comment: post your Vagrantfile and your current provisioning script

Comment: so i figured out that I was trying to edit the host not the VM, so after I vagrant ssh into the VM I am able to make the updates, however I am still having errors with apache2 and the composer install